# Divergence of series $\sin(n+1)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

If we want to prove that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(n+1)$ diverges, can we use the Sandwich theorem for that?

$-1\le \sin(n+1) \le 1$

Since limits as $n$ approaches infinity for $-1$ and $1$ are different that means that $\sin(n+1)$ diverges.

Is this the correct way to prove?

Comment: You will want to use the $n$th term test for divergence, and show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin(n+1)$ does not exist. I think you are trying to do that with the sandwich theorem; however, that is not what the sandwich theorem will say. What the sandwich theorem will say is that if the limit exists, then the limit must lie between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: The easiest way to see that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(n+1)$ diverges is due to the fact that the sequence $\sin(n+1)$ does not tend to $0.$

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can use the *divergence test*. For that, it suffices to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin (n + 1) \neq 0$. And to show that, it suffices to show that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there is some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|n - (\pi/2 + 2k\pi)| < \pi/4$.

This follows from the Archimedean property and the fact that $2 \pi / 4 = \pi/2 > 1$. Moreover, it means that $\sin n > \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ which implies that the limit cannot be zero. There are certainly some details left to be filled in, but this is an argument that relies only on relatively elementary principles.

Answer (score 1):

The [Sandwich Theorem (aka Squeeze Theorem)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) is usually used to show the convergence of a sequence. For that theorem, we would need a lower and upper bound that get closer together as $n\to\infty$. That is not what we have here.

If $|\sin(n)\,|\le\sin(1/2)$, then $|\cos(n)\,|\ge\cos(1/2)$ and
$$
\begin{align}
|\sin(n+1)\,|
&=|\sin(n)\cos(1)+\cos(n)\sin(1)|\tag{1a}\\
&\ge\cos(1/2)\sin(1)-\sin(1/2)\cos(1)\tag{1b}\\
&=\sin(1/2)\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ [sine of a sum formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities)
$\text{(1b):}$ [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality)
$\text{(1c):}$ [sine of a difference formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities)

This says that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}|\sin(n)\,|\ge\sin(1/2)\tag2
$$
That is, the terms of the series do not tend to $0$, so the series diverges.